# titling package in beamer class gives error: "! Undefined control sequence. \if@titlepage"

Tags: beamer, titles, undefined, titling

Using the titling package for a beamer class document results in an error even for the simplest possible setup (see example below). I did not find any documentation that would rule out using titling in a beamer class document. My question thus is:

- Can you help me getting the titling package to work?
- If not, are there good alternatives to make commands like `\thetitle`, `\theauthor`, `\thedate` available in a beamer document?

**Description:**
The following MWE

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{titling} % 
% 
\title{Some title}
\author{A.N. Author}
\date{Some Day}
% 
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}  
\end{document}
```

results in an error

> ! Undefined control sequence.
>
> l.35 \if@titlepage

While the same code compiles fine when the titling package is not loaded. It also runs fine with the titling package when using the article class.

I am using pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) and compile in TeXStudio.

Comment: don't use this package with beamer. Beamer has its own commands and templates here. See e.g. 10.1 Adding a Title Page in the documentation, which points to \insertauthor etc.

Comment: Thanks Ulrike Fischer! Your answer is indeed what I looked for. Would you post it as an answer such that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `titling`package here, since `title`, `author`etc. can be used by default.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
% 
\title{Some title}
\subtitle{Some subtitle}
\author{A.N. Author}
\date{Some Day}
% 
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}  
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but you do not answer the question. I indicated clearly that I would like to use the commands \theauthor, \thetitle, ... from the titling package. I am editing above to highlight this part of the question  as code as should have done from the beginning.